# Does anyone know the algorithm used for navigating a Pac-Man maze?

Tags: algorithm, java-2d, pacman

I need an algorithm for [this pacman maze](http://www.cyberiapc.com/javagames/pacman/pacman.htm). Can anyone help?

Comment: am i pac man or the ghost?  are there enemies?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what kind of algorithm you want, but if you are implementing the movement of the ghosts, then you should read "[Understanding Pac-Man Ghost Behavior](http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior)" by Chad Birch.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a large question.

Anyway, I've yet written a Pac-Man game in both Java and C and I implemented the maze as a matrix filled as follows:
- "-1" if there's a wall;
- "1" if there's a candy;
- else, "0".
To navigate through the maze, you have to use key events. When you'd like to turn left or right, you test if there's a wall ("-1").

I don't know if this answered your question, but feel free to precise if it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Another site with quite some informations on pacman is the [PacMan dossier](http://home.comcast.net/~jpittman2/pacman/pacmandossier.html)